# How can I prevent my Android Location App from crashing on first time run?

Tags: android, android-studio, location, maps

I have created an Android App which opens a Map Fragment and is to create 2 markers:

Marker 1 is the current location (which i believe may be the cause of the problem)

Marker 2 which gets the coords(LatLng) passed from a previous Activity

My problem is that when I run the app for the first time it crashes ... stops responding
I have made sure all the permissions and manifest file is correct.
But i have made the following observation :
After the app crashes if i open Google Maps close everything and run the app again it works fine.

The following error message is generated:

> *2020-07-16 09:51:16.363 3833-3833/com.notbytes.barcodereader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.notbytes.barcodereader, PID: 3833
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
> at com.notbytes.barcodereader.MainActivity2$4.onSuccess(MainActivity2.java:197)
> at com.notbytes.barcodereader.MainActivity2$4.onSuccess(MainActivity2.java:192)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)*

Any help or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could add some relevant parts of the code. It looks like its crashing when you try to get the Lattitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the `getLastLocation()` method might return null, because the `fused location provider` doesn't update the location cache after the device is restarted. If `getLastLocation()` returns null unexpectedly:

1. Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because disabling location also clears the cache.
2. The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings
3. Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create a new client and request location updates yourself. For more information, see [Receive Location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates).

But in your case, I guess you have not added any `check` before getting `latitude` and `longitude`.

Below is a sample code of how to get and set location.

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(
           new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

//I added below if-statement to prevent my app from crash or nullpointerException.

       if (location != null) {
           mLastLocation = location;
           mLocationTextView.setText(
                   getString(R.string.location_text,
                           mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                           mLastLocation.getLongitude(),
                           mLastLocation.getTime()));
       } else {
           mLocationTextView.setText(R.string.no_location);
       }
    }
```

**if this does not solve your problem then please try to add your code as well.**

Comment: I added a the line to handle the NOT NULL, which will then pass the coordinates, but i need to handle the NULL. Ideally, I would like to update until a coordinate is returned. 
What could be added in the ELSE so that I ensure that a cordinate is passed rather than display no_location??

Your help is really appreciated !!!

Comment: The following solved the issue ... but im not sure why since there should be no last known cached location on reboot..

Comment: public void callLocationUpdates(){
        .....{
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if(location!=null) {
                            testMycurr(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())                        }
                        else{
                            callLocationUpdates();
               fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,new LocationCallback(), Looper.getMainLooper());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

Comment: I have updated my answer.